# Pre-commit hook (exit code 2), Xcode, SVN

Tags: c++, xcode, svn

I am working on a project in C++ in Xcode and we are using SVN. Everytime, when I press commit, Xcode show me this:

[BPPC_Project - name of our project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ugda.png)

What can I do, to solve this problem and also use SVN?

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 2)`. The hook is installed on the SVN server's side and this hook seems to be broken. Ask your SVN server admin to double-check this. It can also be possible that your commit does not meet some requirements enforced by this hook script. E.g. maybe this hook checks the length of your commit's log message and rejects your commit because your message is to short.